# How to make one child component - Material dialog - available in/for tow modules?

Tags: angular, angular-material

I have a Material Dialog component which is imported in other component and works fine. A kind of child component. And it's being imported and added
in the root `app.module.ts`:

```
import { PasswordDialogComponent } from './password-dialog/password-dialog.component';
....
declaration:[PasswordDialogComponent, ....]
.....
```

Now I have another module: `dashboard.module.ts` where I want to import the same dialog component in order to be able to use it in other component which belongs to dashboard Module.

The issue is when I declare `PasswordDialogComponent` once again in: `dashboard.module.ts`, I get the following error: **`ERROR in Error: Type PasswordDialogComponent in....src/app/password-dialog/password-dialog.component.ts is part of the declarations of 2 modules:`** which is correct.

So, how can I use the same child component in both/two different modules? Or should I create a new child Component for `dashboard.module.ts` which will normally have the same job and execute the same functionality as `PasswordDialogComponent`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you can do is make a module for your **PasswordDialogComponent** call it dialog.module.ts this module can be used for multiple dialogs later. You can import this module in your **root** and your **dashboard** modules.

So dialog.module.ts look like:

```
import { PasswordDialogComponent } from './password-dialog/password-dialog.component';
@NgModule({
  declarations: [PasswordDialogComponent, ....]
  .....
export class dialogModule { }
```

Your modules look like:

```
import { dialogModule } from './dialog/dialog.module'; // or ../dialog/
@NgModule({
  imports: [dialogModule, ....]
  .....
```

Comment: My Bad... had to think a bout it. A kind of shared module... great. Works!